# href in model string causes mvc to throw Failed to map the path error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have an mvc page that simply needs to display data saved to a database table.  This data is a rendered view so it includes links to other pages within the app.  In my page I'm just using

```
@Html.Raw(Model)
```

to display the string.  What I'm finding is that it attempts to render but once it hits the first link in the page it throws an exception - "Failed to map the path".

Any ideas why it's doing this and how to get around it?

Comment: Are the links in the "rendered view" just pure HTML, or does that data contain further Razor (i.e @Url.Action, etc)?  I think Raw is going to fail if it contains further Razor that needs to be rendered.

Comment: Just pure html.  And, I've tried it without Raw just to see what happens but it does the same thing.

Comment: Another thing that's interesting is that I have a breakpoint on the @Html.Raw line but it never seems to get hit.  I can put breakpoints in other views and they stop as expected.  So I'm wondering if there's something going on between the controller and the model being sent to the view?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the controller on the call to View (i.e. "return View(viewModel);"), does it hit that breakpoint?  If so, can you see your HTML inside of the viewModel variable?  Does it look valid?

Comment: I figured out the issue.  I think because I was just sending the string into the view that it was using that as the view name.  I created a dummy viewmodel object with a string Data property.  Setting the Data property equal to my html and then rendering that in the view worked fine.